# Excel - how to count specific values from one table based on values in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

Hope you are doing well.

I have the following tables:

[image]

This table represents the probability of each possible result of each of the matches (before the matches were played).

[image]

This table represents the actual results of the matches (once they were played).

I am looking for a formula which would fill the cells `B2:F3` in the third table as follows.

[image]

The row 2 (named "Yes") returns the total count of "Yes" match results from table 2 which have a given or higher match result probability in the table 1.

The row 3 (name "No") returns the total count of "No" match results from table 2 which have a given or higher match result probability in the table 1

So for cell `B2`, the formula should count the total of "Yes" match results from table 2 which have a probability of 10% or higher in table 1. It returns "3" because

- Liverpool-Burnley Home Win has a "Yes" in table 2 and a probability of 80% in table 1
- Chelsea-Arsenal Draw has a "Yes" in table 2 and a probability of 35% in table 1
- Tottenham - West Ham Home Win has a "Yes" in table 2 and a probability of 45% in table 1

Similarly, for cell `B3`, the formula should return "5" as there are five match results that have "No" in table 2 and a probability of 10% or higher in table 1.

I understand that the `INDEX` and `COUNTIF` formulas should probably be used, but I have been trying for two days and I am lost how exactly to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include text, not links pictures, so people can work with your content. Also, please edit the question to show what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

Assume your "Table 1" housed in `"Sheet1" A1:D4` and "Table 2" housed in `"Sheet 1" A6:D9` all with column/row header

"Summary table (Table 3) " put in `"Sheet 2" A1:F3` with column/row header

In `"Sheet 2" B2`, copied across to `F2` and all copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$2:$D$4>=MID(B$1,3,2)%)*(Sheet1!$B$7:$D$9=$A2))
```

Comment: I will use SUMPRODUCT too